# How to use Capacity constraint and time window constraint as single solution with minimum cost for VRP?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

This VRP has multiple locations, time windows for each location, multiple vehicles, and weight capacity for each vehicle.

[VRP image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc8Om.png)

I started with Google's OR Tools.I need to get a vehicle routing result for each vehicle considering capcity and time windows of locations. I want to do Capacity constraint and time window constraint as single solution with minimum cost. How to achive this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the sample directory for the routing library:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples

and in particular the cvrp_tw example:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrptw.py

Comment: thank you,  can we use this example (cvrptw.py) with distance matrix @Laurent Perron

Comment: Just create the callback that reads the distance matrix.

Comment: how to modify create_time_evaluator according to the distance matrix @Laurent Perron, can you add an example for cvrptw.py with distance matrix?

Comment: there is a tsp example with distance matrix.

Comment: tsp example hasn't time window constraint, I need to use  cvrptw.py example with distance matrix, I can't convert create_time_evaluator according to the distance. Can you help with this or any example? I add another question -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603847/how-to-replace-locations-array-with-distance-matrix-array-and-modify-create-tim]