# How to replace _locations array with distance matrix array and modify create_time_evaluator according to matrix array in or-tools samples/cvrptw.py

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have a question with multiple locations, time windows for each location, multiple vehicles, and weight capacity for each vehicle. I need to get a vehicle routing result for each vehicle considering the capacity and time windows of locations.

I started with the or-tool example [cvrptw.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrptw.py). and try to add distance matrix as input using the or-tool example [vrp_capacity.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_capacity.py). I added the changed code below.

```
from functools import partial
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def create_data_model():
"""Stores the data for the problem."""
data = {}

data['distance_matrix'] = [
    [
        0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
        468, 776, 662
    ],
    [
        548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
        1016, 868, 1210
    ],
    [
        776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
        1130, 788, 1552, 754
    ],
    [
        696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
        1164, 560, 1358
    ],
    [
        582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
        1050, 674, 1244
    ],
    [
        274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
        514, 1050, 708
    ],
    [
        502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
        514, 1278, 480
    ],
    [
        194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
        662, 742, 856
    ],
    [
        308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
        320, 1084, 514
    ],
    [
        194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
        274, 810, 468
    ],
    [
        536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
        730, 388, 1152, 354
    ],
    [
        502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
        308, 650, 274, 844
    ],
    [
        388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
        536, 388, 730
    ],
    [
        354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
        342, 422, 536
    ],
    [
        468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
        342, 0, 764, 194
    ],
    [
        776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
        388, 422, 764, 0, 798
    ],
    [
        662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
        536, 194, 798, 0
    ],
]
data['num_locations'] = len(data['distance_matrix'])
data['time_windows'] = \
      [(0, 0),
       (75, 85), (75, 85), 
       (60, 70), (45, 55), 
       (0, 8), (50, 60),
       (0, 10), (10, 20), 
       (0, 10), (75, 85), 
       (85, 95), (5, 15), 
       (15, 25), (10, 20), 
       (45, 55), (30, 40)] 
data['demands'] = \
      [0, 
       1, 1, 
       2, 4, 
       2, 4, 
       8, 8, 
       1, 2, 
       1, 2, 
       4, 4, 
       8, 8] 
data['time_per_demand_unit'] = 5  
data['num_vehicles'] = 4
data['vehicle_capacity'] = 15
data['vehicle_speed'] = 83  
data['depot'] = 0
return data




def manhattan_distance(position_1, position_2):

return (
    abs(position_1[0] - position_2[0]) + abs(position_1[1] - position_2[1]))





def create_demand_evaluator(data):

_demands = data['demands']

def demand_evaluator(manager, node):
   
    return _demands[manager.IndexToNode(node)]

return demand_evaluator


def add_capacity_constraints(routing, data, demand_evaluator_index):

capacity = 'Capacity'
routing.AddDimension(
    demand_evaluator_index,
    0,  # null capacity slack
    data['vehicle_capacity'],
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    capacity)


def create_time_evaluator(data):

def service_time(data, node):
   
    return data['demands'][node] * data['time_per_demand_unit']

def travel_time(data, from_node, to_node):
    """Gets the travel times between two locations."""
    if from_node == to_node:
        travel_time = 0
    else:
        travel_time = manhattan_distance(data['locations'][from_node], data[
            'locations'][to_node]) / data['vehicle_speed']
    return travel_time

_total_time = {}
# precompute total time to have time callback in O(1)
for from_node in range(data['num_locations']):
    _total_time[from_node] = {}
    for to_node in range(data['num_locations']):
        if from_node == to_node:
            _total_time[from_node][to_node] = 0
        else:
            _total_time[from_node][to_node] = int(
                service_time(data, from_node) + travel_time(
                    data, from_node, to_node))

def time_evaluator(manager, from_node, to_node):
    """Returns the total time between the two nodes"""
    return _total_time[manager.IndexToNode(from_node)][manager.IndexToNode(
        to_node)]

return time_evaluator


def add_time_window_constraints(routing, manager, data, time_evaluator_index):
"""Add Global Span constraint"""
time = 'Time'
horizon = 120
routing.AddDimension(
    time_evaluator_index,
    horizon,  # allow waiting time
    horizon,  # maximum time per vehicle
    False,  # don't force start cumul to zero since we are giving TW to start nodes
    time)
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
# Add time window constraints for each location except depot
# and 'copy' the slack var in the solution object (aka Assignment) to print it
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
    if location_idx == 0:
        continue
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
    routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(index))
# Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node
# and 'copy' the slack var in the solution object (aka Assignment) to print it
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data['time_windows'][0][0],
                                            data['time_windows'][0][1])
    routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(index))
    # Warning: Slack var is not defined for vehicle's end node
    #routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(self.routing.End(vehicle_id)))



def print_solution(manager, routing, assignment):  # pylint:disable=too-many-locals
"""Prints assignment on console"""
print(f'Objective: {assignment.ObjectiveValue()}')
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
capacity_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Capacity')
total_distance = 0
total_load = 0
total_time = 0
for vehicle_id in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
    distance = 0
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        load_var = capacity_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        slack_var = time_dimension.SlackVar(index)
        plan_output += ' {0} Load({1}) Time({2},{3}) Slack({4},{5}) ->'.format(
            manager.IndexToNode(index),
            assignment.Value(load_var),
            assignment.Min(time_var),
            assignment.Max(time_var),
            assignment.Min(slack_var), assignment.Max(slack_var))
        previous_index = index
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index,
                                                 vehicle_id)
    load_var = capacity_dimension.CumulVar(index)
    time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
    slack_var = time_dimension.SlackVar(index)
    plan_output += ' {0} Load({1}) Time({2},{3})\n'.format(
        manager.IndexToNode(index),
        assignment.Value(load_var),
        assignment.Min(time_var), assignment.Max(time_var))
    plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {0}m\n'.format(distance)
    plan_output += 'Load of the route: {}\n'.format(
        assignment.Value(load_var))
    plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}\n'.format(
        assignment.Value(time_var))
    print(plan_output)
    total_distance += distance
    total_load += assignment.Value(load_var)
    total_time += assignment.Value(time_var)
print('Total Distance of all routes: {0}m'.format(total_distance))
print('Total Load of all routes: {}'.format(total_load))
print('Total Time of all routes: {0}min'.format(total_time))
# [END solution_printer]


def main():
"""Solve the Capacitated VRP with time windows."""
# Instantiate the data problem.
# [START data]
data = create_data_model()
# [END data]

# Create the routing index manager.
# [START index_manager]
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(data['num_locations'],
                                       data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
# [END index_manager]

# Create Routing Model.
# [START routing_model]
routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
# [END routing_model]

def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
# [END transit_callback]

# Define cost of each arc.
# [START arc_cost]
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)


# Add Capacity constraint.
# [START capacity_constraint]
demand_evaluator_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
    partial(create_demand_evaluator(data), manager))
add_capacity_constraints(routing, data, demand_evaluator_index)
# [END capacity_constraint]

# Add Time Window constraint.
# [START time_constraint]
time_evaluator_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
    partial(create_time_evaluator(data), manager))
add_time_window_constraints(routing, manager, data, time_evaluator_index)
# [END time_constraint]

# Setting first solution heuristic (cheapest addition).
# [START parameters]
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
    routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(2)
search_parameters.log_search = True
# [END parameters]

# Solve the problem.
# [START solve]
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
# [END solve]

# Print solution on console.
# [START print_solution]
if solution:
    print_solution(manager, routing, solution)
else:
    print('No solution found!')
# [END print_solution]


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I changed,

1. Replace _locations array with distance matrix array
2. Remove distance_evaluator_index and add distance callback.

**Now I need to modify create_time_evaluator according to the distance matrix and apply it to time_evaluator_index. How can I achieve this and get better results?**

I need to achieve Capacity constraints and time window constraints using distance matrix as a single solution with minimum cost. **Is this the better way for my problem?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Capacity constraint and time window constraint as single solution with minimum cost for VRP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70516662/how-to-use-capacity-constraint-and-time-window-constraint-as-single-solution-wit)

Comment: No, any help? thanks in advance

Comment: use the tsp distance matrix example. The code is modular, time windows, capacity, and orthogonal to the distance evaluator.

Comment: distance matrix added with distance callback. It is ok. My question is  modify create_time_evaluator according to the distance matrix and apply it to time_evaluator_index. cvrptw.py exapmle do this based on location array `    _locations = \
            [(4, 4), # depot
             (2, 0), (8, 0), # locations to visit
             (0, 1), (1, 1),
             (5, 2), (7, 2),
             (3, 3), (6, 3),
             (5, 5), (8, 5),
             (1, 6), (2, 6),
             (3, 7), (6, 7),
             (0, 8), (7, 8)]`